# AJAX + PHP + MongoDB Performance on Amazon AWS

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Lets say I had the following scenario:

- Amazon AWS EC2 large server
- Mongodb collection with 100000 documents
- 10 AJAX calls per second (across all users) to a PHP script that takes post data and updates one document from that collection. That document is updated using mongo `update()`.

Am I going to run into performance issues? Do I need to figure out some other way to do this?

Basically I'm using AJAX to send new data to update a collection when a user makes a change to a page.

One solution I thought of is making an array of changes that user makes and then letting the user commit all of those changes at the end (similarly to how submitting a form works), but it'd be nice to know I had the option of just making the 10 calls per second.

Comment: I imagine that low level of load will be fine for the free tier! Why not try it? (10 calls/sec should be fine in total. But if you're wanting 10 calls/sec/user with a large number of users, that's not going to work).

Comment: Is there another technology that I should be using instead? It's not 10 calls/sec/user it's just 10 calls/sec overall. I figured 100 users all simultaneously using would be making one change every 10 seconds which is 10 calls/sec total

Comment: AJAX is fine for that, and as I say, that load is sufficiently low you can probably get away with a smaller server.